# In R, how to do named entity recognition?

Tags: r, nlp, opennlp, named-entity-recognition

I have looked at this guide https://lincolnmullen.com/projects/dh-r2/nlp.html and this youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0lpQludiI-0 which both use the same method. When I try and replicate the results from the biography example in the first link, all I get as the output of

```
entities(bio_doc, kind = "person")
```

is

```
character(0)
```

This was the same result when I used a different input string as well. I saw this thread [Efficient Named Entity Recognition in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58169707/efficient-named-entity-recognition-in-r) and they got the same result as well (character(0)). I see that it went unanswered, so I was wondering if perhaps someone now has an answer to it? Has this method just been deprecated? I would very much appreciate anyone's insight.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a minimal [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. But the minimal code necessary to replicate the problem in the question itself. External links are prone to link rot plus it's not always clear if everyone followed the steps exactly.

Comment: Perhaps that https://github.com/trinker/entity could be used, as  Hanjo Jo'burg Odendaal mentioned on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58169707/efficient-named-entity-recognition-in-r